# Pass an array as a query string in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with firstname, lastName, zipcode..etc, in addition to multi value input, in which the user check many checkboxes (which will be an array).

I wanna submit this form using angular js $http, and pass them as a query string, currently I have it like this:

firstName=test&lastName=test&homeZip=44551&carInterested=honda%2Cford%2Ctoyota

but my requirement is to be like this:

firstName=test&lastName=test&homeZip=44551&carInterested=honda&carInterested=ford&carInterested=toyota

here is my code:

```
       $scope.signUp = function() {
        $scope.formData.carInterested= $scope.selection
        console.log ($scope.formData);

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : '/sonmeUr/../',
          transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
          data    : $scope.formData  

         })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }); 
    }
```

and in my service I have this:

```
        .factory( "transformRequestAsFormPost", function() {
            function transformRequest( data, getHeaders ) {
                var headers = getHeaders();
                headers[ "Content-type" ] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

                return( serializeData( data ) );
            }

            return( transformRequest );

            function serializeData( data ) {
                if ( ! angular.isObject( data ) ) {
                    return( ( data == null ) ? "" : data.toString() );
                }
                var buffer = [];
                for ( var model in data ) {
                    if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty( model ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var value = data[ model ];
                    buffer.push(
                        encodeURIComponent( model ) +
                        "=" +
                        encodeURIComponent( ( value == null ) ? "" : value )
                    );
                }
                var source = buffer
                    .join( "&" )
                    .replace( /%20/g, "+" )
                ;
                return( source );
            }
        }
    );
```